# Java regex: newline + white space

Tags: java, regex, text-manipulation

should be simple, but I'm going crazy with it.

Given a text like:

```
line number 1
line number 2
 line number 2A
line number 3
 line number 3A
 line number 3B
line number 4
```

I need the Java regex that deletes the line terminators then the new line begin with space, so that the sample text above become:

```
line number 1
line number 2line number 2A
line number 3line number 3Aline number 3B
line number 4
```

Comment: Try `"\r?\n\W+"`.  I haven't tried it, so I don't want to register it as an answer.  In case you haven't checked it out already, you can find some specifics about Java regex here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html ... If you are guaranteed that "line" is the first text on a given line, you could also try `"\r?\n[^l]+"`.

Comment: @Mike M: Won't work on Apple's OSs

Comment: Should work on OS-X though, right?  Are people still using old versions of Apple?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`yourString.replaceAll("\n ", " ");` this wont help?

Comment: 1) The question says: _if you encounter line that begins with <blank> remove both the blank and the new line. 2) '\n' is not portable

Comment: @MatteoSp, remeber that Stings are immutable, so in fact you need `yourString = yourString.replaceAll("\n ", " ");` or something like that, because calling method wont change String object itself permanently. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 11):

```
String res = orig.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]+\\s", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps to make it  cross-platform:

```
String pattern = System.getProperty("line.separator") + " ";
string.replaceAll(pattern, "");
```

Comment: Well, the system `line.separator` doesn't really help, since you don't know if the files were created on the system where the JVM is running

Answer (score 2):

`"\n "` This is should do the trick if you are in Unix LF mode. For DOS like you need to match CRLF `"\r\n "`. Did check with RegexBuddy looking fine.